# LARAVEL - Missing required parameters

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

hi im new to coding and ive been watching this youtube tutorial about a simple server side processing crud and datatable in laravel and im getting this error which i have no idea why im getting it.

I am trying to create an update function to my code but cant cuz of this error. I have a feeling this is because of my update url but im using the same syntax in the tutorial so can you god tier people help me.

> Missing required parameters for [Route: Clients.update] [URI:
>   Clients/{Client}]. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\clients\clients.blade.php)

this is my view code

```
<div id="formmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Client Form</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>{{-- header --}}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="result" id="result"></span>
                <form method="post" id="client_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="client_name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_name" id="client_name" placeholder="Enter Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="client_address">Addres</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_address" id="client_address" placeholder="Enter Addres">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="client_date">Birth Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="client_bdate" id="client_bdate">
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input  type="text" name="action" id="action">
                    <input  type="text" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savebtn" id="savebtn" value="Add">
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('#client_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url;
    if($('#action').val() == 'Add')
    {
    url = "{{ route('Clients.store') }}";
    }else{
    url = "{{ route('Clients.update') }}";
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                var html = '';
                if(data.errors)
                {
                    html = '<diV class="alert alert-danger">';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
                    {
                        html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
                    }
                    html += '</div>';
                }
                if(data.success)
                {
                    alert("add");
                    html = '<diV class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
                    $('#client_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
                $('#result').html(html);
            }
        })
});
```

my controller code

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'client_name'       =>  'required',
            'client_address'    =>  'required',
            'client_bdate'      =>  'required'
        );

        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if($error->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$error->errors()->all()]);
        }

        $form_data = array(
            'client_name'       =>  $request->client_name,
            'client_address'    =>  $request->client_address,
            'client_bdate'      =>  $request->client_bdate
        );

        Clients::find($request->hidden_id)->update($form_data);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Updated']);

    }
```

Edit...
My route

```
Route::resource('/Clients', 'clientsCont');
```

Comment: Please provide the route definition used in your `web.php` file

Comment: Route::resource('/Clients', 'clientsCont');

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you are missing second parameter.

So try like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'client_name'       =>  'required',
            'client_address'    =>  'required',
            'client_bdate'      =>  'required'
        );

        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if($error->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$error->errors()->all()]);
        }

        $form_data = array(
            'client_name'       =>  $request->client_name,
            'client_address'    =>  $request->client_address,
            'client_bdate'      =>  $request->client_bdate
        );
        // You should get your client in variable $client
        //Clients::find($request->hidden_id)->update($form_data);
        $client->update($form_data);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Updated']);
    }
```

Also note if you want to your code look simplier you can validate your request like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'client_name'       =>  'required',
            'client_address'    =>  'required',
            'client_bdate'      =>  'required'
        ])
        $client->update($form_data);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Updated']);
    }
```

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file remove the {} from `Clients/{Client}` or preferably change it to: `Clients/update`, when you put {} around some text, you are binding some parameter (actually Eloquent Model), and you should provide it (provide the ID) when you call the route.

Read more [Laravel Documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: i dont have any {} in my routes file..... Route::resource('/Clients', 'clientsCont');

Comment: im calling the route via ```url = "{{ route('Clients.update') }}";``` how do i provide it an ID?

Comment: well by using Route::resource you are making several routes, that one of them is `clients/{client}` if you want to solve your issue you either have to stop using {} and route model binding, or provide the model id when you use the route.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's put certain conventions in place.

Change your route definition to

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ClientsCont');
```

By convention, controller names should be camel case and start with a capital letter. The route names are usually lower case.

Next, ensure that your controller file is correctly named `ClientsCont.php` and also the class name should be `ClientsCont`. Finally, you have to provide a second parameter to your `update()` method to hold the client object to update.

**ClientsCont.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Client;

class ClientsCont extends Controller
{
    // class definition

    public function update(Request $request, Client $client)
    {
        $rules = array(
            'client_name'       =>  'required',
            'client_address'    =>  'required',
            'client_bdate'      =>  'required'
        );

        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if($error->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$error->errors()->all()]);
        }

        $form_data = array(
            'client_name'       =>  $request->client_name,
            'client_address'    =>  $request->client_address,
            'client_bdate'      =>  $request->client_bdate
        );

        $client->update($form_data);

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Updated']);

    }
}
```

Now, setup your Ajax request properly.

```
$('#client_form').on('submit', function(event){
    var url;
    if($('#action').val() == 'Add')
    {
        url = "{{ route('clients.store') }}";
    }else{
        url = "{{ route('clients.update') }}";
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var html = '';
            if(data.errors)
            {
                html = '<diV class="alert alert-danger">';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
                {
                    html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
                }
                html += '</div>';
            }
            if(data.success)
            {
                alert("add");
                html = '<diV class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
                $('#client_form')[0].reset();
                $('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
            $('#result').html(html);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Usually using `return false;` is the preferred way for stopping default event action and propagation.

> **[return false;]** Usually seen in jQuery code, it Prevents the browsers default behaviour, Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM, and immediately Returns from any callback.

See this [medium write-up](https://medium.com/@jacobwarduk/how-to-correctly-use-preventdefault-stoppropagation-or-return-false-on-events-6c4e3f31aedb) for full details.

Also, from your code, certain of your ajax settings are unnecessary and should be omitted so that their default values are used. These default values are usually sufficient for most forms.

For instance, using jQuery Ajax setting of `processData: false` disables processing the form data and uses the `toString()` method of the object to form the request data string.

> When you set data to a general object other than a string with processData set to false jQuery doesn't process the object. The object is passed to the Ajax call exactly as it is and used as if it was a String. This by default calls the toString method and sends the result to the sever as the data in the Ajax request.

See [this](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/jquery/8941-getting-started-with-jquery-advanced-ajax.html?start=1) for full description. Be sure you need this setting or you discard it all together.

Another Ajax setting you probably need to discard is `contentType: false`, except you have a good reason for setting it.